# Loop over an array of Keras networks in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've tried searching but I don't think I can find an answer to this...  I am working on a neural network that derives its training data from outputs of an **array** of other neural networks when they are fed with simulated data.  There is no "dataset"; each minibatch generates a new set of simulated data.  So, if it's to be able to run efficiently, I need to aggregate the outputs from the array of other networks in a `tf.function` (which will run once per minibatch).  But...  I cannot for the life of me figure out if there is a way to loop over an array of **non-Tensors** -- everything seems to be about indexing into tensors (e.g. with `tf.gather`).

To be clear, the elements of the array are objects that contain `tf.keras.models.Sequential` objects with further `tf.function`s that further transform their outputs and train those networks, and they all work great on-graph.  I just need to be able to hook into those somehow.  Here is a very rough simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
networks_outputs = tf.TensorArray(size=N, dtype=tf.float32, element_shape=blah, infer_shape=True)
for n in tf.range(N):
    input_data_n = tf.concat([input_data[:, n], input_data[:, N:N + K]], axis=1)
    network_output = networks_array[n].some_tf_function(input_data_n)
    networks_outputs = networks_outputs.write(n, network_output)
networks_outputs = networks_outputs.stack()
```

-- but this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor
```

Comment: If `N` is a fixed integer, you can just use `range` instead of `tf.range`. The issue is that the latter returns tensors, and if `networks_array` is a list or numpy array, you cannot index into those with tensors.

Comment: @xdurch0 Ah that is super helpful, thank you!  Yes it works if I replace tf.range with range and replace N with, say, 3.  However, N is currently a tf.constant -- in any particular instantiation, it is a fixed number, but I need to be able to rerun the code with N set to different values.  Is this possible somehow?  If keep N (instead of the literal 3), i still get the same error, even with range.  (I'm also looking into using tf.switch_case and building a list of `some_tf_function`s off-graph, which looks possible if not.)